# Capture output of ImageDataGenerator without saving images to drive?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tf.keras

I'm using image augmentation to train my model, applying transforms like brightness and color shifts.  I like to preview the effects of the augmentations before putting them into use.  Normally, I do it like this:

```
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip = True,
                             fill_mode = "nearest",
                             zoom_range = 0.3,
                             rotation_range=360)

i = 0

for batch in datagen.flow_from_directory(directory='./my_images/,
                                         batch_size = 1,
                                         save_to_dir='.',
                                         save_prefix='aug',
                                         save_format='jpeg'):
    i += 1
    if i > 2:
        break  # Yields two images
```

Then I open the images and look at them, or read them in and print them to my notebook.  But I don't like this- it's clunky.  Is there a way to directly capture the altered images produced by my generator?  I'd like to add them to an array.

Thanks!

Comment: What prevents you to just add them to a list?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro  OH MY GOSH.  Of course.  I can just append "batch" to a list... How silly of me!  Thank you!  It always helps to have an extra pair of eyes!